# deferred write data from network on disk in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, io

How I can collect request from network (~200 req /sec) and write it on disk or Database at certain intervals?
In Android, I used blocking queue and Timer for this purpose, but JavaScript lack this.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a inMemory Cache and use setInterval to persist data to DB or disk for perticular interval and empty the cache after its done.

This is one way for achieving, you can make efficient one with some caching frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval() to call a function on a certain interval in your code.